# interstitial error android unable to pause activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob, android-fragmentactivity

I have one issue with interstitial ads .
I am getting error unable to pause activity when I am trying to handle `onAdClosed()` method

Here I am using fragments

Here I am posting my logcat output

```
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause  
activity {com.social_sweep.app/com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity}:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):at
android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2846)

03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349): at
android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2802)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349): at
android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):at
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:133)
 03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1220)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):    at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):    at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):    at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):    at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):    at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):    at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):    at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):    at
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1280)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):    at
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1291)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):    at
android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:548)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):    at
android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:532)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):    at
com.social_sweep.app.SelectEvent$3$1.onAdClosed(SelectEvent.java:461)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):    at
com.google.android.gms.internal.t.onAdClosed(Unknown Source)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):    at
com.google.android.gms.internal.ab$a.onTransact(Unknown Source)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):    at
android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):    at
com.google.android.gms.internal.bs$a$a.onPause(Unknown Source)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):    at
com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity.onPause(Unknown Source)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):    at
android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5219)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):    at
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1225)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):    at
android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2833)
03-18 19:28:50.169: E/AndroidRuntime(26349):    ... 12 more
```

Here is my code what I am doing ,

```
 if (fragment != null) {
             interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

             public void onAdLoaded() {

             displayInterstitial();

             }

             public void onAdClosed() {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left,
                            R.animator.slide_out_right,
                            R.animator.slide_in_left,
                            R.animator.slide_out_right)
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)..commitAllowingStateLoss();

            // update selected item and title, then close the
            // drawer

            getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(Title);
             };

             });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever manage to get over this bug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you are getting is due to your attempting to perform your Fragment manipulation AFTER #onSaveInstanceState has been called on your Activity. Ie your Activity has been stopped and possibly destroyed, undoubtedly because the Ad Activity has been displayed. When the Ad is closed your Activity will be restarted (possibly even recreated), so do whatever UI manipulation you want at that point.

On a side note:

**DO NOT** call displayInterstitial from AdListener#onAdLoaded.

This will provide a really poor user experience as well as cause you mountains of problems with ads showing up when you least expect them such as after existing your Activity.

Instead call DisplayInterstitial at a natural break point in your app.

Comment: thanks for your answer and guiding me  can you tell me the right way to display ads  i am using asynctask in post execute method i am displaying ads

Comment: Just call #displayInterstitial at a natural break point in your app like between levels of a game.

Comment: ok i did it but in #onAdClosed() how to resume activity that causes error

Comment: Just remove your code from onAdClosed - it won't work from there, and I don't understand what you are trying to do with it. What problem are you trying to solve with that code?

Comment: well i want to replace fragment when user close Ad\

Comment: But your Activity no longer exists. There is nothing in which to replace a fragment.

Comment: yes i know that from your comment. but how can i achive

Comment: Replace the fragment when your Activity is restarted.

Comment: @William every time it not calling onRestart() method ,my requirement is start channel after ads get close 9/10 it working fine but some time it cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in onAdClosed():-

```
if(!isAdded()) { return; }
```